# White Label .NET Application

Tags: .net, windows-installer

We sell a service that comprises of a .NET application packaged in an MSI that combines with a webservice.

We have had quite a few customers wanting to reselling our application under their brand/logo etc. All we really need to do is change the task bar icon, desktop icon, start menu icon, possibly description under those icons, and information in our about / support details. This way we can have the same app selling under 10 brands, hopefully with a lot more customers.

We can change the task bar icon, about / support using a config variable as they are active, but not the start menu / desktop icons or text under the icons as they are placed when installed.

We do not want to fork our code for each reseller (this might happen 10 times), but want a way that we can either install under a different brand, or just after install - change everything to their settings. Keep in mind our app is currently installed across Win2k, winxp, vista, 7, embedded.

After looking - it does not seem there is a good way to do this....any thoughts would be appreciated.

Cheers
Scott

Comment: It is actually possible to edit the resources of an application after compilation. You can simply use file open inside Visual Studio and change the icons and any text in there, if using resources for the text.

Answer (score 1):

That's an interesting question. You might look at using "[Resource-Only Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984332%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)" that contain the specific graphic and string resources for each client in question for each named assembly. Then you will build all of them but for a specific client only include their assembly in the installer and use the app.config to specify the assembly name that is used in the ResourceManager constructor.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the way you prepare the MSI package. If you use WiX, then using preprocessor should resolve the problem.

Another option is to use MSI transforms, where data in the MSI package can be changed at installation time via transform

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367447(v=vs.85).aspx